# How can i add this in my react native project?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image: Project Image]

**As you can see in the image I have selected the item i want to create i don't know what it's called can any one help please?**

Comment: You might be able to find examples by searching for "progress step bar" or similar. But for StackOverflow, this question is way too broad.

Comment: Its can be called a step indicator, progress bar. You can look such components up on the internet.

Comment: That might help Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use step indicator. Please check following npm. You can customize this npm according to your need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-step-indicator

[image]